# Streaming music from Ubuntu Server 14 over VPN

Tags: server, vpn, music, streaming, mediaserver

Apologies if this has been asked already - I've been searching around and haven't found anything too helpful for what I'm looking to do.

I'm looking to have my Ubuntu Server(14) host my music and have some kind of streaming service installed on it so that I can listen to my music over my network at home and also while I travel on my laptop.

I already have OpenVP, Samba, and LAMP installed and running correctly, I'm just not sure what the next step is or what's already available to achieve what I'm looking to do.

Edit:

Realizing my vagueness of the question, my intent is to be able to be able to listen to my music via the web.  I was looking at a package called *ampache* using a LAMP setup, but I'm not sure this is achieving what I want.

My goal:

1. Connect to my VPN
2. Navigate to my server in a web browser
3. Listen to music
4. Disconnecting from my VPN will stop music

I apologize if this is equally vague, but this is new unfamiliar territory for me.

Comment: There are really way too many ways to do this, to give you a direct answer. I'm using _minidlna_ as a DLNA server for example. You don't really need samba though.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Does minidlna rely on some kind of VNC player?  I was hoping that I could do this over the web with a website.  I was looking at ampache, have you experience with that?

Comment: No, DLNA is a standard protocol for streaming. I've never used _ampache_ no. There are plenty of solutions which provide a web site to stream through, though, if that's what you want. Most graphical players like Rhythmbox, Banshee, etc… have a upnp/dlna plug-in available, so you can just play music streamed from the dlna server directly in the player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found that achieved exactly what I was trying:

[Ampache's Git Repo (GitHub)](https://github.com/ampache/ampache)

Ampache is a streaming service written in PHP.  It's a work in progress and they've just recently came out with version 3.0.  Using this service, you can store your music in a directory (and multilevel directory) and direct Ampache to catalog that directory with your music.  Ampache takes it from there, store the paths and information in a MySQL database, and streams directly to your web interface.

Here's a bit of a dated guide to it, but was the only one I could find:

[Step-by-step guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-the-ampache-streaming-music-server-in-ubuntu-12.04-lts)

To get Ampache running you need to have a LAMP stack running (which is step on in the guide, if you don't know how to setup the stack.  It references a web-interface called SWAT, which is no longer supported by Ubuntu.  It also references Samba, which is (obviously) supported, but only needed to move your music from your desktop to your server.

Also, the repo on Ubuntu's apt-get is outdated, to get the current (mainly) bug free version, you'll have to unpack the files from their Git Hub.